# Want to remove the number at the end of this string and store to new variable in flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, integer

`15 Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz  2009`
i want to remove the number(2009) from the end of this string and store it to a new variable. and i also want to remove the integer from the begining of this string too in **flutter**..
so the final output must be like this:

***string name="Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz"**

`int year =2009`

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for this case. Define method:

```
  String removeDigits(final String s) {
    return s.replaceAll(new RegExp(r"[0-9]+"), "");
  }
```

Then use it:

```
final String address = "15 Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz  2009";


String name = removDigits(address);
```

Output:

```
Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz
```

To get year:

```
final String year = Characters(address).takeLast(4).string;
```

Comment: thank you. but how to store the year at the end to a seperate variable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little test that accomplishes what you want.

```dart
void main() {
  test('Remove first and last string', () {
    var s = '15 Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz  2009';
    var parts = s.split(' ');// Split on every occurence of a space
    var year = parts.removeLast();// save and remove the year from the list
    s = parts.sublist(1).join(' ');// drop the first item
    expect(year, '2009');
    expect(s, 'Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz ');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        String _str = '15 Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz  2009';
        String _str2 = _str.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\d+'), '').trim();
        print(_str2);
        String year = _str.substring(_str.length - 4, _str.length);
        print(year);
      },
      child: Text('Pressed'),
    );
```

Comment: can i get the year from this?

Comment: Is year is always gonna be at last of the string?

Comment: yes,year is always at the end of the string

Comment: If year always gonna be at the end of the string then you can use `substring` like this `String year = _str.substring(_str.length - 4, _str.length);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
String message = "15 Clarendon Hills Astralis Shiraz  2009";
var letterDetected = false;
var year = "";
message.runes.forEach((int rune) {
  var character=new String.fromCharCode(rune);
  if(character.contains(RegExp("[a-z]"))){
    letterDetected = true;
  }
  if(character.contains(RegExp("[0-9]")) && letterDetected){
    year = year+character;
  }
});
print("year $year");//<== use year as
message = message.replaceAll(RegExp("[0-9]"), "");
print("messsage ${message}"); //<== use normal sentence
```